# How do you print variables outside of a class?

Tags: python, class

I am very new to Python. I am currently using Jupyter Notebook and I need to print the variable "pos_best_g" outside of the following class:

```
class PSO():
    def __init__(self,costFunc,x0,bounds,num_particles,maxiter):
        global num_dimensions

        num_dimensions=len(x0)
        err_best_g=-1                   # best error for group
        pos_best_g=[]                   # best position for group

        # establish the swarm
        swarm=[]
        for i in range(0,num_particles):
            swarm.append(Particle(x0))

        # begin optimization loop
        i=0
        while i < maxiter:
            #print i,err_best_g
            # cycle through particles in swarm and evaluate fitness
            for j in range(0,num_particles):
                swarm[j].evaluate(costFunc)

                # determine if current particle is the best (globally)
                if swarm[j].err_i < err_best_g or err_best_g == -1:
                    pos_best_g=list(swarm[j].position_i)
                    err_best_g=float(swarm[j].err_i)

            # cycle through swarm and update velocities and position
            for j in range(0,num_particles):
                swarm[j].update_velocity(pos_best_g)
                swarm[j].update_position(bounds)
            i+=1

        # print final results
        print ('FINAL:')
        print (pos_best_g)
        print (err_best_g)

initial=[5,5,5,5,5]               # initial starting location [x1,x2...]
bounds=[(-10,10),(-10,10),(-10,10),(-10,10),(-10,10)]  # input bounds [(x1_min,x1_max),(x2_min,x2_max)...]
PSO(func1,initial,bounds,num_particles=15,maxiter=30)
```

At the moment I get the following result:

```
FINAL:
[4.999187204673611, 5.992158863901226, 4.614395966906296, 0.7676323454298957, 8.533876878259441]
0.001554888332705297
```

However, I don't know how to extract the results as they are all within an In[] cell and not an Out[] cell.

What do I need to do to enable this?

Many thanks

Comment: Why is this a class? It doesn't use any internal state. It should probably just be a function, or refactored into a class that does.

Comment: You can either move this code into a regular function (using a class's `__init__` method is a bit weird) and then `return` it from the function, or make it a class instance variable by going through the `self` parameter.

Comment: You need to do more work on passing information among Python blocks: look at functional parameters and return values, class methods and attributes.  You also need to learn more code design in general.  You haven't yet grasped the proper uses of `class` and `__init__`.  For now, drop the class idea entirely and writ this as a main program or perhaps one or two functions.  Once you get that designed, *then* worry about how to encapsulate the algorithm.

Comment: Many thanks all. I appreciate the advice. I am trying to use Python as part of my Uni project for extracting solar cell parameters and am learning as I go. I have dived in the deep end really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this:
1. return "pos_best_g" variable at the end of "**init**" function.

2. define a variable before class and define it as global variable inside the class, then change its value at the end of the **init**

like:

```
your_new_variable
class PSO():
def __init__(self,costFunc,x0,bounds,num_particles,maxiter):
    global num_dimensions
    global your_new_variable


    ...

    print ('FINAL:')
    print (pos_best_g)
    print (err_best_g)
    your_new_variable = pos_best_g
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the result you want to extract as class attributes

```
class PSO():
    def __init__(self,costFunc,x0,bounds,num_particles,maxiter):
        ...

        # Set class attributes
        self.pos_best_g = pos_best_g
        self.err_best_g = err_best_g
```

Then you can access it from the object

```
pso = PSO(func1,initial,bounds,num_particles=15,maxiter=30)

# print final results
print ('FINAL:')
print (pso.pos_best_g)
print (pso.err_best_g)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is your own defined class, right? You can try adding a getter method and later call this method in Jupyter notebook to store the output results in variables as follows:

Just include these small functions inside your class

```
def get_pos_best(self):
   return self.pos_best_g

def get_err_best(self):
   return self.err_best_g
```

Now, inside your notebook do the following:

```
object_PSO = PSO(costFunc,x0,bounds,num_particles,maxiter)
list_you_want = object_PSO.get_pos_best()
error_you_want = object_PSO.get_err_best()
```

Good luck!